# How filter first record from array of object?

Tags: javascript

Hi what is best solution for get first record from array of objects.

I have something like this: this is just example,

```
var arr = [
    {date:Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100, (CET), value:2222},
    {date:Mon Jan 18 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100, (CET) (CET), value:1222},
    {date: Sun Jan 17 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100, (CET) (CET), value:1222}
]
```

First solution is sort it and then take arr[0], but can i use array filter method for it?

Comment: Uh, can you do `arr[0]` ?

Comment: i think so, but first i need sort it, so i try find other solutions.

Comment: Do you actually mean the object with the earliest `date` property?

Comment: your array format is not correct. in third object there is no date key in the array.

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of first element
`arr.shift()`

To access first element
`arr[0]`

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking to get the first element of this array?

```
var elemOne = arr[0];

console.log(elemOne);
```

This should show you the first element of

```
{date:Fri Jan 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100, (CET), value:2222}
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: Can someone share why all these seemingly correct answers are getting downvotes?

Comment: I think it is because someone already commented "Uh, can you do arr[0] ?" and the answer is so obvious that an answer is not necessary.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this to get first element of object

```
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[0].date);
console.log(arr[0].value);
```